# Selenium error on Chrome version 113- Message: javascript error: Object.hasOwn is not a function

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Chrome has been updated recently and some of the functions raises

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Object.hasOwn is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.93)
```

This happens for clicks, and find_elements and I can't find any solution to this. I was able to use `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', element)` for clicks and it started working, but it fails for `find_element`s. Any solution?

Comment: That property should be there unless something is deleting it. You should show more code

Comment: @pguardiario more code will bring more confusion, the issue is not my previous code

Comment: Possibly the website is doing it but I would bet on it's your code.

Answer (score 0):

have the same issue...looks like you can use

```
elements = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelectorAll('var');")
```

This will help you find elements on the page, then you can click on them with the process you described...I hope this helps to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I raised this issue in the official group a week ago，waiting for the reply.

`driver.find_element` report errors